# How to stop JPA Repository projection excerpts from returning embedded lists on ManyToMany relationships

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities User and Role. They each have a `@ManyToMany` relation with each other (to find roles associated with user, and vice-versa).
I have several projections for each, and both repositories have an `excerptProjection`. Whenever I make a call to get all resources `/api/users`, the resource list returns as expected. But when I make a call to a specific resource `/api/users/1`, it has an `_embedded` resource list of the other type.

When I remove the excerpt from the RoleRepository, making a call to `/api/users/1` stops the embedded roles from appearing, but `/api/roles/1` shows embedded users.

**Code**

Entities:

```java
public class User {
  private long id;
  private Instant createdAt;
  private Instant updatedAt;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String email;

  @Lazy
  @JsonIgnore
  @Where(clause = NOT_DELETED)
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(
    name = "user_role_rel", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
  private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
  // other stuff omitted 
}

public class Role {
  private long id;
  private Instant createdAt;
  private Instant updatedAt;
  private String name;
  private String description;

  @Lazy
  @JsonIgnore
  @Where(clause = NOT_DELETED)
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
  private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
  // other stuff omitted 
}
```

Projections:

```java
@Projection(name = "summary", types = { User.class })
public interface Summary {
  Long getId();
  String getUsername();
  String getFirstName();
  String getLastName();
  String getEmail();
}

@Projection(name = "summary", types = { Role.class })
public interface Summary {
  Long getId();
  String getName();
  String getDescription();
}
```

Repositories:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource( excerptProjection = Summary.class )
public interface UserRepository extends SoftDeleteRepository<User, Long> {}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface RoleRepository extends SoftDeleteRepository<Role, Long> {}
```

**Requests/Responses**

`GET /api/users/1`

```
{
    "createdAt": "2019-06-15T10:37:16.280Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-06-15T10:37:16.280Z",
    "username": "ironman",
    "firstName": "Tony",
    "lastName": "Stark",
    "email": "tony@starkindustries.com",
    "_id": 1,
    "_links": {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

`GET /api/roles/1`

```
{
    "createdAt": "2019-06-15T10:37:15.984Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-06-15T10:37:15.984Z",
    "name": "ROLE_ADMIN",
    "description": "Admin role",
    "_id": 1,
    "_embedded": {
        "users": [
            {
                "firstName": "Tony",
                "lastName": "Stark",
                "username": "ironman",
                "email": "tony@starkindustries.com",
                "id": 1,
                "_links": {
                    // omitted
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

The first one works as expected, only the visible fields are shown.
The second one keeps throwing in that `_embedded` field.

If I add the excerpt to both repositories (which is what I intend) then both calls would add the embedded lists.

Applying a projection to either of these requests stops the embedded list from appearing, but obviously no projection is applied by default.

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

**Recently I was facing same kind of issue.
Hope below code will help you to resolve the issue.**

```
 @Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.getProjectionConfiguration().addProjection(Summary.class);
  }
}
```

**Please check below url for more details:**

[url](https://gigsterous.github.io/engineering/2018/01/26/spring-data-rest-projections.html)